# Run iptables-save before shutdown/reboot

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, bash

I have installed iptables-persistent on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and search for a solution that I don't need to save the iptables configuration (iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4) every time before a reboot or shutdown.

So I created the following script (/etc/init.d/iptables-save) with the command and made it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

After that I created a link in /etc/rc6.d:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/iptables-save /etc/rc6.d/K01iptables-save
```

Now it should be executed before a shutdown, but it doesn't work.

Why doesn't that work? Is there another way to execute this one command before a shutdown/reboot?

Comment: You are not using ufw?

Comment: This is 18.04?  Isn't that using systemd?  Did  you manually make those symlinks?  I wonder if you have to do a `systemctl daemon-reload` for the systemd-sysv-generator to see that you changed something.  Anyway try another reboot after that change.

Answer (score 2):

The package `netfilter-persistent` or `iptables-persistent` should contain all you're looking for.

Comment: I have netfilter-persistent and iptables-persistent both installed on my system, but what do I need to configure?

Comment: Just enable the service with `systemctl enable netfilter-persistent`. You can test with `systemctl start|stop netfilter-persistent`. There is also a configuration file in `/etc/default/netfilter-persistent`.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/all/netfilter-persistent/filelist

Comment: I enabled `netfilter persistent` and started the service but it still doesn't work. In the directory `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/` there are the two files
`15-ip4tables  25-ip6tables`